# PHP timeout running MSSQL SP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to run a MSSQL stored procedure from PHP using PDO. I do this all the time but with this SP it's timing out. The SP is rather complex and takes about 4 minutes to run.

I am calling it like this:

```
$setDate = '2014-01-03';

$queryMain = $coreDB->prepare("exec sp_ard :runDate");
$queryMain->bindParam("runDate",$setDate);
$queryMain->execute();

$e = $queryMain->errorInfo();
$d = $queryMain->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($e);
print_r($d);
```

When I run the page it runs for a minute or so then produces this error:

```
Array ( [0] => 08S01 [1] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. )
```

I know the SP works fine. I can run it straight from the MSSQL management console. It takes about 4 minutes to run from there but it works fine.

I am trying to figure out how I can run this from PHP.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you make up to 4 minutes or more on php.ini for the runtime script timeout? Standard is 60 seconds.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: Do you know if the SP completes or if the timeout is just the connection?  4 minutes is way to long for a page to load.  This needs to be a background process.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to configure the timeout using PDO.

> ## [PDO::setAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)
>
> ```
> public bool PDO::setAttribute ( int $attribute , mixed $value )
> ```
>
> `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`: Specifies the timeout duration in seconds. Not all drivers support this option, and it's meaning may differ from driver to driver. For example, sqlite will wait for up to this time value before giving up on obtaining an writable lock, but other drivers may interpret this as a connect or a read timeout interval.

Comment: It's not clear whether this would apply to your scenario, but [MSDN documents `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff628164(v=sql.90).aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had not tried that but I just did it and it's still timing out. Not sure what is going on with this. It's driving me nuts. Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

If your problem is a timeout, you can use the function [set_time_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

If you pass a zero to the function, no time limit is imposed.

Also, make sure you are closing all the connections after using them.

Hope this help!

Comment: Please note the error comes from the SQL Server driver; PHP itself is not timing out.

Comment: @gryphes thanks for the help. I do have the time limit set to 0 and I am closing the connection. That's not the issue. I think like Alvaro said the error seems top be coming from the SQL driver. Not sure how to get around it. Thanks again